# Как убрать значение из localStorage после перезагрузки?

Tags: javascript, jquery, сессия, localstorage

Нужно построить такой алгоритм:

1) В поисковый запрос ввожу текст,
2) Нажимаю **Поиск**,
3) Страница перезагружается,
4) Введенный текст сохраняется там же в строке поиска.
5) При последующей перезагрузке страницы, введенный текст удаляется

Сохраняю в `localStorage` (возможно это неправильно, т.к. данные не нужно долго хранить).

1) Как убрать введенный текст при следующей перезагрузке?
2) С помощью чего лучше реализовать?

Использую [этот](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html) плагин для автокомплита, т.ч. код выглядит просто:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="art"]').autoComplete({
        minChars: 4,

        source: function(term, response) {
            //формирую выдачу
        renderItem: function (item, search){
            // оформляю выпадающие подсказки
        onSelect: function(e, term, item){
            // Что происходит при клике (тут вся магия)
            $('.search .inp #art').val(item.data('detail'));
            localStorage.setItem('searchable', item.data('detail'));

            document.location.href = "http://example.com/items/" + item.data('brand') + "/" + item.data('id') + ".html";

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: я так понимаю, вы из поиска переходите на страницу товаров бренда. На эту же страницу можно попасть по этой же урл и без поиска. И когда вы пришли из поиска, то в строке нужно оставить поисковый запрос. так что ли? и да, сохраняете уж в `sessionStorage`, если хранить не надо долго. А еще если результаты поиска разбиты на страницы, то логично, чтобы при переходе по ним слово в строке тоже оставалось

Comment: да, при переходе из поиска (при формировании выдачи в нее (выдачу) попадает название товара item.data('detail') и при клике я перехожу на страницу товара

Comment: мне вот, честно, не понятно зачем на конечной странице товара рисовать поисковый запрос. Имхо его есть смысл рисовать, когда мы находимся в списке результатов. Когда же товар найден, то зачем это надо вообще?

Comment: я с вами согласен, но так нужно:)

Comment: но в общем-то вопрос в том, возможно ли как-то удалить `sessionStorage` после перезагрузки?

Comment: дак проверить, если есть значение, вписать в строку и  удалить. в чем сложность-то?

Comment: так после первой перезагрузки оно там тоже есть, мне как-то счет перезагрузкам вести надо)

Comment: дак вы удаляете значение то? если не удалять, понятно, что никуда оно не денется оттуда

Comment: смотрите, я ввожу текст в поиск, нажимаю "найти", страница перезагружается и в поисковой строке есть значение из `sessionStorage` (это нормальное поведение), но мне нужно чтобы после следующей перезагрузке оно исчезло. Я понимаю что его нужно удалить, но какое условие при этом должно быть я не пойму. Чтобы при первой перезагрузке оно было, а потом исчезло.

Comment: вы при загрузке странице сами руками туда вписываете ведь значение? берете его из хранилища? вот и удалите сразу же. Просто удалить и все, тогда первый раз оно будет, а на последующие нет. добавьте в вопрос код, где вы заполняете это поле на странице товара

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На странице товара (`example.com/items/brand/id.html`) вы должны проверить наличие значения в храилище. Если оно есть, то вписать его в поисковую строку и затем удалить его.

```
$(function(){
   var search = localStorage.getItem('searchable');
   if(search){
      $(".search .inp #art").val(search);
      localStorage.removeItem('searchable');
   } 
});
```

тогда при следующем обновлении страницы в хранилище уже не будет данного ключа.

Answer (score 2):

так же можно почистить полностью хранилище их консоли

localStorage - `localSrotage.clear()`

Другие хранилища где данные хрянятся не так долго
sessionStorage(хранится до закрытия вкладки) - `sessionSrotage.clear()`
cookies - `document.cookies = ''`